# C++/CLI equivalent of C#'s DateTime.Now.Ticks

Tags: c++-cli

I want to get the equivalent method in C++/CLI as `DateTime.Now.Ticks` in C#".

I have tried:

```
long a = DateTime::Now::Ticks;
long a = DateTime::Now::Ticks();
long a = DateTime::Ticks;
long a = DateTime::Ticks();
```

But all failed... What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you appear to need is first:

```
DateTime localDate = DateTime::Now;
```

This gives you the time now in an object, then

```
long long a = localDate.Ticks;
```

This queries the `Ticks` property, which is a `long long`, not just a simple `long`.

As a one-liner:

```
long long a = DateTime::Now.Ticks;
```

Comment: Thank you Ken, I will mark this as the answer. :)  Update: I don't know how to mark it as an answer, I'm new to this site. :(  @Ken Y-N

Comment: @KaKaShi_CantAim [Here is how to do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/222560). Please also don't forget to upvote if you feel it is worth it!